# Re-sort a sorted array by different key

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have this array, which has already been sorted by uploadTime

```
    [
      { id: 1133, userId: 101697, uploadTime: '2020-09-14T16:19:16.000Z' },
      { id: 1132, userId: 101543, uploadTime: '2020-09-14T16:17:27.000Z' },
      { id: 1131, userId: 101697, uploadTime: '2020-09-14T16:09:49.000Z' },
      { id: 1130, userId: 101697, uploadTime: '2020-09-14T16:09:16.000Z' },
      { id: 1128, userId: 101543, uploadTime: '2020-09-09T21:48:46.000Z' },
      { id: 1127, userId: 101543, uploadTime: '2020-09-09T21:41:41.000Z' },
      { id: 1126, userId: 101543, uploadTime: '2020-09-09T21:35:37.000Z' },
      { id: 1125, userId: 101543, uploadTime: '2020-09-09T19:41:57.000Z' },
      { id: 1082, userId: 101577, uploadTime: '2020-08-21T15:24:35.000Z' },
      { id: 1049, userId: 101589, uploadTime: '2020-08-15T23:31:42.000Z' },
      { id: 1040, userId: 101589, uploadTime: '2020-08-14T15:04:01.000Z' },
      { id: 1036, userId: 101589, uploadTime: '2020-08-13T00:09:43.000Z' },
      { id: 1035, userId: 101527, uploadTime: '2020-08-12T20:07:34.000Z' },
      { id: 1034, userId: 101612, uploadTime: '2020-08-12T17:33:26.000Z' },
      { id: 996, userId: 101589, uploadTime: '2020-08-11T15:20:11.000Z' }, 
      { id: 889, userId: 101626, uploadTime: '2020-08-06T14:47:18.000Z' }, 
      { id: 864, userId: 101589, uploadTime: '2020-08-05T15:23:50.000Z' }, 
      { id: 863, userId: 101589, uploadTime: '2020-08-05T14:42:14.000Z' }, 
      { id: 852, userId: 101589, uploadTime: '2020-08-04T18:05:07.000Z' }, 
      { id: 851, userId: 101589, uploadTime: '2020-08-04T17:57:58.000Z' }
    ]
```

Now I want to resort it, but only for objects with the same userId and uploadTime is less than 24 hours from current time. The output should be something like this:

```
    [
      { id: 1133, userId: 101697, uploadTime: '2020-09-14T16:19:16.000Z' },
      { id: 1131, userId: 101697, uploadTime: '2020-09-14T16:09:49.000Z' },
      { id: 1130, userId: 101697, uploadTime: '2020-09-14T16:09:16.000Z' },
      { id: 1132, userId: 101543, uploadTime: '2020-09-14T16:17:27.000Z' },
      { id: 1128, userId: 101543, uploadTime: '2020-09-09T21:48:46.000Z' },
      { id: 1127, userId: 101543, uploadTime: '2020-09-09T21:41:41.000Z' },
      { id: 1126, userId: 101543, uploadTime: '2020-09-09T21:35:37.000Z' },
      { id: 1125, userId: 101543, uploadTime: '2020-09-09T19:41:57.000Z' },
      { id: 1082, userId: 101577, uploadTime: '2020-08-21T15:24:35.000Z' },
      { id: 1049, userId: 101589, uploadTime: '2020-08-15T23:31:42.000Z' },
      { id: 1040, userId: 101589, uploadTime: '2020-08-14T15:04:01.000Z' },
      { id: 1036, userId: 101589, uploadTime: '2020-08-13T00:09:43.000Z' },
      { id: 1035, userId: 101527, uploadTime: '2020-08-12T20:07:34.000Z' },
      { id: 1034, userId: 101612, uploadTime: '2020-08-12T17:33:26.000Z' },
      { id: 996, userId: 101589, uploadTime: '2020-08-11T15:20:11.000Z' }, 
      { id: 889, userId: 101626, uploadTime: '2020-08-06T14:47:18.000Z' }, 
      { id: 864, userId: 101589, uploadTime: '2020-08-05T15:23:50.000Z' }, 
      { id: 863, userId: 101589, uploadTime: '2020-08-05T14:42:14.000Z' }, 
      { id: 852, userId: 101589, uploadTime: '2020-08-04T18:05:07.000Z' }, 
      { id: 851, userId: 101589, uploadTime: '2020-08-04T17:57:58.000Z' }
    ]
```

Edit: I end up do it like this, a bit longer than the other approach:

```
    let dict = {}
    let dictArr = []
    let resultGroup = []
    let resultNoGroup = []
    
    temp.forEach((item) => {
        if (!dict[item.userId]) {
            dict[item.userId] = []
        }
        dict[item.userId].push(item)
        dict[item.userId].sort((a, b) => a.uploadTime - b.uploadTime)
    })
    
    for (let key in dict) {
        dictArr.push(dict[key])
    }
    
    dictArr.sort((a, b) => (a[0].uploadTime > b[0].uploadTime ? -1 : 1))
    
    for (let i = 0; i < dictArr.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < dictArr[i].length; j++) {
            const timeDiff = Math.abs(
                Math.round(
                    (new Date().getTime() -
                        new Date(dictArr[i][j].uploadTime).getTime()) /
                        (1000 * 3600)
                )
            )
            if (timeDiff <= 24) {
                resultGroup.push(dictArr[i][j])
            } else {
                resultNoGroup.push(dictArr[i][j])
            }
        }
    }
    
    resultNoGroup.sort((a, b) => (a.uploadTime > b.uploadTime ? -1 : 1))
    
    const result = [...resultGroup, ...resultNoGroup]
    
    console.log(result)
```

This work for me as expected!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now I want to resort it, but only for objects with the same userId and uploadTime is less than 24 hours from current time.

This time the sort need to be changed a bit (see the comments in the code):

If both dates are less than 24 hours sort on **userId** else continue with uploadTime in order to preserve the order.

```js
var data = [
    {id: 1133, userId: 101697, uploadTime: '2020-09-14T16:19:16.000Z'},
    {id: 1132, userId: 101543, uploadTime: '2020-09-14T16:17:27.000Z'},
    {id: 1131, userId: 101697, uploadTime: '2020-09-14T16:09:49.000Z'},
    {id: 1130, userId: 101697, uploadTime: '2020-09-14T16:09:16.000Z'},
    {id: 1128, userId: 101543, uploadTime: '2020-09-09T21:48:46.000Z'},
    {id: 1127, userId: 101543, uploadTime: '2020-09-09T21:41:41.000Z'},
    {id: 1126, userId: 101543, uploadTime: '2020-09-09T21:35:37.000Z'},
    {id: 1125, userId: 101543, uploadTime: '2020-09-09T19:41:57.000Z'},
    {id: 1082, userId: 101577, uploadTime: '2020-08-21T15:24:35.000Z'},
    {id: 1049, userId: 101589, uploadTime: '2020-08-15T23:31:42.000Z'},
    {id: 1040, userId: 101589, uploadTime: '2020-08-14T15:04:01.000Z'},
    {id: 1036, userId: 101589, uploadTime: '2020-08-13T00:09:43.000Z'},
    {id: 1035, userId: 101527, uploadTime: '2020-08-12T20:07:34.000Z'},
    {id: 1034, userId: 101612, uploadTime: '2020-08-12T17:33:26.000Z'},
    {id: 996, userId: 101589, uploadTime: '2020-08-11T15:20:11.000Z'},
    {id: 889, userId: 101626, uploadTime: '2020-08-06T14:47:18.000Z'},
    {id: 864, userId: 101589, uploadTime: '2020-08-05T15:23:50.000Z'},
    {id: 863, userId: 101589, uploadTime: '2020-08-05T14:42:14.000Z'},
    {id: 852, userId: 101589, uploadTime: '2020-08-04T18:05:07.000Z'},
    {id: 851, userId: 101589, uploadTime: '2020-08-04T17:57:58.000Z'}
];

data.sort(function (a, b) {
    // compute the difference with current date
    var dcta = (new Date()).getTime() - (new Date(a.uploadTime)).getTime();
    var dctb = (new Date()).getTime() - (new Date(b.uploadTime)).getTime();

   // convert then in hours
    var h1 = (((dctb) / 1000) / 60)/60;
    var h2 = ((dctb / 1000) / 60)/60;

    // if both are less than 24hours....    
    if (h1 <=24 && h2 <= 24) {
        return b.userId - a.userId;
    } else {
        return (new Date(b.uploadTime)).getTime() - (new Date(a.uploadTime)).getTime();
    }
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(data).replace(/\},/g, '},\n'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let testArray = [
    { id: 1133, userId: 101697, uploadTime: '2020-09-14T16:19:16.000Z' },
    { id: 1132, userId: 101543, uploadTime: '2020-09-14T16:17:27.000Z' },
    { id: 1131, userId: 101697, uploadTime: '2020-09-14T16:09:49.000Z' },
    { id: 1130, userId: 101697, uploadTime: '2020-09-14T16:09:16.000Z' },
    { id: 1128, userId: 101543, uploadTime: '2020-09-09T21:48:46.000Z' },
    { id: 1127, userId: 101543, uploadTime: '2020-09-09T21:41:41.000Z' },
    { id: 1126, userId: 101543, uploadTime: '2020-09-09T21:35:37.000Z' },
    { id: 1125, userId: 101543, uploadTime: '2020-09-09T19:41:57.000Z' },
    { id: 1082, userId: 101577, uploadTime: '2020-08-21T15:24:35.000Z' },
    { id: 1049, userId: 101589, uploadTime: '2020-08-15T23:31:42.000Z' },
    { id: 1040, userId: 101589, uploadTime: '2020-08-14T15:04:01.000Z' },
    { id: 1036, userId: 101589, uploadTime: '2020-08-13T00:09:43.000Z' },
    { id: 1035, userId: 101527, uploadTime: '2020-08-12T20:07:34.000Z' },
    { id: 1034, userId: 101612, uploadTime: '2020-08-12T17:33:26.000Z' },
    { id: 996, userId: 101589, uploadTime: '2020-08-11T15:20:11.000Z' },
    { id: 889, userId: 101626, uploadTime: '2020-08-06T14:47:18.000Z' },
    { id: 864, userId: 101589, uploadTime: '2020-08-05T15:23:50.000Z' },
    { id: 863, userId: 101589, uploadTime: '2020-08-05T14:42:14.000Z' },
    { id: 852, userId: 101589, uploadTime: '2020-08-04T18:05:07.000Z' },
    { id: 851, userId: 101589, uploadTime: '2020-08-04T17:57:58.000Z' }
];




testArray = testArray.sort((x, y) => {
    return (y.userId - x.userId);
});

testArray = testArray.filter(currentObj => {
    return (new Date() - new Date(currentObj.uploadTime)) < 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
})

    
    
    console.log(testArray);
```

We sort comparing two different attributes of the objects.
Now you will have the users sorted by userId and then the their upload times with latest to oldest.

Result:

```
[ { id: 1133,
    userId: 101697,
    uploadTime: '2020-09-14T16:19:16.000Z' },
  { id: 1131,
    userId: 101697,
    uploadTime: '2020-09-14T16:09:49.000Z' },
  { id: 1130,
    userId: 101697,
    uploadTime: '2020-09-14T16:09:16.000Z' },
  { id: 1132,
    userId: 101543,
    uploadTime: '2020-09-14T16:17:27.000Z' } ]
```

Comment: Your result messed up the order by uploadTime, after we cluster the userId we still have to maintain the uploadTime order from newest to oldest

Comment: Check now. You can't have two different sorting at the time time like that. So if you sort the users by userId then you can sort by time.

Comment: no your sorting is wrong because he asked .... less than 24 hours...

Comment: Yes. I did not add the filter before hand. Added it now.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var uploads=[{"id":1035,"userId":101527,"uploadTime":"2020-08-12T20:07:34.000Z"},{"id":1125,"userId":101543,"uploadTime":"2020-09-09T19:41:57.000Z"},{"id":1126,"userId":101543,"uploadTime":"2020-09-09T21:35:37.000Z"},{"id":1127,"userId":101543,"uploadTime":"2020-09-09T21:41:41.000Z"},{"id":1128,"userId":101543,"uploadTime":"2020-09-09T21:48:46.000Z"},{"id":1132,"userId":101543,"uploadTime":"2020-09-14T16:17:27.000Z"},{"id":1082,"userId":101577,"uploadTime":"2020-08-21T15:24:35.000Z"},{"id":851,"userId":101589,"uploadTime":"2020-08-04T17:57:58.000Z"},{"id":852,"userId":101589,"uploadTime":"2020-08-04T18:05:07.000Z"},{"id":863,"userId":101589,"uploadTime":"2020-08-05T14:42:14.000Z"},{"id":864,"userId":101589,"uploadTime":"2020-08-05T15:23:50.000Z"},{"id":996,"userId":101589,"uploadTime":"2020-08-11T15:20:11.000Z"},{"id":1036,"userId":101589,"uploadTime":"2020-08-13T00:09:43.000Z"},{"id":1040,"userId":101589,"uploadTime":"2020-08-14T15:04:01.000Z"},{"id":1049,"userId":101589,"uploadTime":"2020-08-15T23:31:42.000Z"},{"id":1034,"userId":101612,"uploadTime":"2020-08-12T17:33:26.000Z"},{"id":889,"userId":101626,"uploadTime":"2020-08-06T14:47:18.000Z"},{"id":1130,"userId":101697,"uploadTime":"2020-09-14T16:09:16.000Z"},{"id":1131,"userId":101697,"uploadTime":"2020-09-14T16:09:49.000Z"},{"id":1133,"userId":101697,"uploadTime":"2020-09-14T16:19:16.000Z"}];

var last24hoursByUserId = 
  uploads
  .filter(upload=>
    new Date() - new Date(upload.uploadTime) 
    <
    24*60*60*1000
  )
  .sort((a,b)=>
    a.userId+a.uploadTime<b.userId+b.uploadTime?-1:1
  )
;

console.log(last24hoursByUserId);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer starts by first parsing the `uploadTime` string. I then checks if `uploadTime` is after `yesterday` and store it as `isWithin24Hours`. I save this data in a separate object `sortData` to not pollute or mutate the objects in `testArray`.

```js
const testArray = [
    { id: 1133, userId: 101697, uploadTime: '2020-09-14T16:19:16.000Z' },
    { id: 1132, userId: 101543, uploadTime: '2020-09-14T16:17:27.000Z' },
    { id: 1131, userId: 101697, uploadTime: '2020-09-14T16:09:49.000Z' },
    { id: 1130, userId: 101697, uploadTime: '2020-09-14T16:09:16.000Z' },
    { id: 1128, userId: 101543, uploadTime: '2020-09-09T21:48:46.000Z' },
    { id: 1127, userId: 101543, uploadTime: '2020-09-09T21:41:41.000Z' },
    { id: 1126, userId: 101543, uploadTime: '2020-09-09T21:35:37.000Z' },
    { id: 1125, userId: 101543, uploadTime: '2020-09-09T19:41:57.000Z' },
    { id: 1082, userId: 101577, uploadTime: '2020-08-21T15:24:35.000Z' },
    { id: 1049, userId: 101589, uploadTime: '2020-08-15T23:31:42.000Z' },
    { id: 1040, userId: 101589, uploadTime: '2020-08-14T15:04:01.000Z' },
    { id: 1036, userId: 101589, uploadTime: '2020-08-13T00:09:43.000Z' },
    { id: 1035, userId: 101527, uploadTime: '2020-08-12T20:07:34.000Z' },
    { id: 1034, userId: 101612, uploadTime: '2020-08-12T17:33:26.000Z' },
    { id: 996, userId: 101589, uploadTime: '2020-08-11T15:20:11.000Z' },
    { id: 889, userId: 101626, uploadTime: '2020-08-06T14:47:18.000Z' },
    { id: 864, userId: 101589, uploadTime: '2020-08-05T15:23:50.000Z' },
    { id: 863, userId: 101589, uploadTime: '2020-08-05T14:42:14.000Z' },
    { id: 852, userId: 101589, uploadTime: '2020-08-04T18:05:07.000Z' },
    { id: 851, userId: 101589, uploadTime: '2020-08-04T17:57:58.000Z' }
];

// use timestamp to produces the same output for future readers
const now = 1600122461595 // Date.now(); 
const yesterday = now - (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

// create complementary data needed for sort
const sortData  = new Map(testArray.map(({id, uploadTime}) => {
  uploadTime = Date.parse(uploadTime);
  return [id, { uploadTime, isWithin24Hours: uploadTime > yesterday }];
}));

testArray.sort((a, b) => {
  const _a = sortData.get(a.id), _b = sortData.get(b.id);
  return _b.isWithin24Hours - _a.isWithin24Hours   // isWithin24Hours DESC
      || _a.isWithin24Hours && b.userId - a.userId // userId DESC if isWithin24Hours = 1
      || _b.uploadTime - _a.uploadTime;            // uploadTime DESC
});

console.log(testArray);
console.table(testArray); // check browser console for this output
```

I use `_b.isWithin24Hours - _a.isWithin24Hours` (`isWithing24Hours DESC`) to move the record to the front that are within 24 hours. This check functions as XOR and will return if the values for `_a.isWithin24Hours` and `_b.isWithin24Hours` are different from each other.

The next check is `_a.isWithin24Hours && b.userId - a.userId`. `_a.isWithin24Hours` will move on to the next check if both are not within 24 hours (both are the same due to the previous check). However if both are within 24 hours the check `b.userId - a.userId` (`userId DESC`) is used .

The last check `_b.uploadTime - _a.uploadTime` (`uploadTime DESC`) is used if both are within 24 hours and have the same `userId`, or if both are not within 24 hours.